# How can I use true type font in my TextView?

Tags: java, android

I tried to implement "Font Awesome" reffering this 
[source](https://bitbucket.org/informatic0re/awesome-font-iconview/overview)

I did these procedure but my Application shut down as soon as it lauches.
What was wrong with this?

1. I copied `values/attrs.xml`. and pasted to my application(No changes in content)
2. I copied content of `values/strings.xml`, and pasted into strings.xml in my App.
3. I copied both `layouts/icon.xml` and `grid.xml`, and pasted into my App(No changes in content)
4. I copied `assets/icons.ttf`, and pasted into my App(No changes in content. It's a font file)
5. I copied `src/com.example.IconView/IconView.java` to my App(No changes in content)
6. I added these lines into my `MainActivity.java`

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.grid);
   GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   grid.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.icons, R.layout.icon));
   ```

Then my current code looks like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid);
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    grid.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.icons, R.layout.icon));       

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.hide();
```

However, my app shut downs automatically as soon as it lauched.
How can I fix these, and enable font awesome?

**LogCat**

```
08-12 21:07:35.931: E/Trace(31646): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-12 21:07:36.041: D/webcoreglue(31646): netstack: Memory Cache feature is ON
08-12 21:07:36.062: W/(31646): init htc webcore
08-12 21:07:36.122: W/dalvikvm(31646): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e19468)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sample/com.example.sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at com.example.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
08-12 21:07:36.122: E/AndroidRuntime(31646):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check your logcat for errors, and post them if they are not clear.

Comment: Download commonsware.com/Android/Android-src-2_1.zip and you will find an Android project that shows loading a TrueType font.

Comment: `R.layout.icon` does not contain a `TextView` which is a required for using `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()`.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I added LogCat to my question. But I have no idea what to do with it:(

Comment: @vikram so what should I do??

Comment: Could anyone create own new project and do the same thing?

Comment: My comment above is not the problem. What do you have on line 62?

Comment: @vikram `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: Can you post your entire code above?

Comment: @vikram okay Hold on please

Comment: @vikram http://pastie.org/8229393 here it is

Comment: Your `onCreate()` calls `setContentView()` twice. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and `setContentView(R.layout.grid)`. In this case, `R.layout.grid` will be used to find the layout components. Do you have a `WebView` with id `R.id.webView1` in `R.layout.grid`?

Comment: @vikram I have a WebView with id `R.id.webView1`

Comment: In fact I'd like to erase `grid.xml` and `icon.xml` if possible.  All I want to do it using FontAwesome's icon in my MainActivity.xml layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35284/discussion-between-vikram-and-mkk)

Comment: @vikram Thanks for your lecture. It was so helpful. By the way, I tried to do the same on right side of Drawer. I added code into `SimpleSideDrawer.java`, and `activity_behind_right_simple.xml layout`. Of course, I followed your instruction. It won't say any error on Eclipse. But my Application shuts down as soon as it launches. Do you have any idea about that? Was I supposed to do something else to work right side Drawer menu? I cleaned my project and tried it but it fails.

Comment: @vikram Please see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195187/why-application-shuts-down-as-soon-as-its-launched-even-if-theres-no-error-cau