# Why Application shuts down as soon as it's launched even if there's no error caution?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three xml files for layouts such as

1. activity_behind_left_simple.xml
2. activity_behind_right_simple.xml
3. activity_main.xml

I implemented textViews to `activity_behind_left_simple.xml`
and it shows the list of Menu. It works fine.

So I did the same on `activity_behind_right_simple.xml`, too.

However, now application shuts down as soon as it's launched:(

Why is that? What's wrong with right side?
**activity_behind_left_simple.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/leftBehindMenuScroll" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
            android:text="People" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <jp.fureco.IconView 
                android:id="@+id/iconViewItem4"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
                android:text="Visitor" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**activity_behind_right_simple.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/rightBehindMenuScroll" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
            android:text="Messages" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <jp.fureco.IconView 
                android:id="@+id/iconViewItem5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
                android:text="Received" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**SimpleSideDrawer.java**

```
    ....
   public View setLeftBehindContentView(int leftBehindLayout) {
        final View content = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(leftBehindLayout, mLeftBehindBase);

        String[] icons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icons);
        IconView iv4 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem4);
        iv4.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
        iv4.setText(icons[8]);

        IconView iv5 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem5);
        iv5.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
        iv5.setText(icons[315]);


        mLeftPaddingRect = new Rect(content.getPaddingLeft(), content.getPaddingTop(), content.getPaddingRight(), content.getPaddingBottom());
        mLeftBehindView = content;
        return content;
    }        

    ....
```

Then if I remove this part, application won't shuts down anymore.
How can I fix?

```
IconView iv5 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem5);
iv5.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
iv5.setText(icons[315]);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    getSize();

    mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.hide();


    mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
    mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);
    mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple);
....
```

**SimpleSideDrawer.java** I've found this. Does this matter?

```
public View setRightBehindContentView(int rightBehindLayout) {
    final View content = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(rightBehindLayout, mRightBehindBase);
    mRightPaddingRect = new Rect(content.getPaddingLeft(), content.getPaddingTop(), content.getPaddingRight(), content.getPaddingBottom());
    mRightBehindView = content;
    return content;
}
```

**part2**

```
public View setLeftBehindContentView(int leftBehindLayout) {
    final View content = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(leftBehindLayout, mLeftBehindBase);

    String[] icons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.icons);

    IconView iv4 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem4);
    iv4.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
    iv4.setText(icons[25]);

    IconView iv5 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem5);
    iv5.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
    iv5.setText(icons[26]);

    IconView iv6 = (IconView) findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem6);
    iv6.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "icons.ttf"));
    iv6.setText(icons[117]);        

    mLeftPaddingRect = new Rect(content.getPaddingLeft(), content.getPaddingTop(), content.getPaddingRight(), content.getPaddingBottom());
    mLeftBehindView = content;
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, whenever you get a chance, drop by: [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35284/discussion-between-vikram-and-mkk).

Comment: @vikram I'll be waiting for you in chat:) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a reference to the inflated layout. try this with all the views you are 
acessing inside setLeftBehindContentView method:

```
     e.g:  

     IconView iv5 = (IconView) content.findViewById(R.id.iconViewItem5);
```

Note: i am assuming the view corresponding to R.id.iconViewItems  lies inside the inflated layout file.

Comment: No, it still shuts down automatically

Comment: make sure you have inflated the right_behind layout before using any of its component. my answer would work only if you have already inflated the right_behind view in the java file.

Comment: I followed what Jon said then no error occurs anymore. However icon still won't be shown up on right side:(

Comment: I just added other code to my Question. Please check. It might be the reason why.

Comment: if it doesn't throw error anymore but the icon is still not shown, you better look at the xml :)  there might be some problem with sizes.

Comment: I added another code to the bottom of my question. Could it be the reason why? It seems it's only loading left side

Comment: try moving the icon_view iv5 related code and any other view that is part of the right_behind.xml from the  setLeftBehindContentView method to the setRightBehindContentView method. Now you can access them without throwing error using my code. and make sure you are using the right paddings etc for both of them.

Comment: No. That's not the point. I have icons on both left and right side. so I cannot remove icon_view iv5. The point is how to make it work on right side as same as left side:)

Comment: Is it only inflating left side? `final View content = ((LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(leftBehindLayout, mLeftBehindBase);`? How can I inflate both left and right?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're inflating `activity_behind_right_simple.xml` anywhere. As far as I can tell you should be getting a NPE when you try to modify iv5.

edit: if you add the code below to your main layout and enclose the `ScrollViews` in a `FrameLayout` this will let it inflate everything during `setContentView()`.

```
<include
        layout="@layout/leftScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<include
        layout="@layout/rightScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I added the content of `MainActivity.Java` in which there is `mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple);` is stated

Comment: Try using `<include>` from your Main Layout and you should be able to inflate everything during `onCreate()` Without seeing main_activity.xml all I can suggest is that you use `<include>` from your Main Layout and have it reference the two other Scroll Views. You will need to give them proper names though.

Comment: Now, no error occurs but `iconViewItem5` won't show its icon:(